# How do you run as many tasks as will fit in memory, each running all all cores, in Windows HPC?

Tags: hpc

I'm using Microsoft HPC Pack 2012 to run video processing jobs on a Windows cluster.  A run is organized as a single job with hundreds of independent tasks.  If a single task is scheduled on a node, it uses all cores, but not at nearly 100%.  One way to increase CPU utilization is to run more than one task at a time per node.  I believe in my use case, running each task on every core would achieve the best CPU utilization.  However, after lots of trying I have not been able to achieve it.  Is it possible?

I have been able to run multiple tasks on the same node on separate cores.  I achieved this by setting the job UnitType to Node, setting the job and task types to IsExclusive = False, and setting the MaximumNumberOfCores on a job to something less than the number of cores on the machine.  For simplicity, I would like to one run task per core, but typically this would exhaust the memory budget.  So, I have set EstimatedProcessMemory to the typical memory usage.

This works, but every set of parameters I have tried leaves resources on the table.  For instance, let's say I have a machine with 12 cores, 15GB of free RAM, and each task consumes 2GB.  Then I can run 7 tasks on this machine.  If I set task MaximumNumberOfCores to 1, I only use 7 of my 12 cores.  If I set it to 2, suppose I set EstimatedProcessMemory  to 2048.  HPC interprets this as the memory PER CORE, so I only run 3 tasks on 2 cores and 3 tasks on 1 core, so 9 of my 12 cores.  And so on.

Is it possible to simply run as many tasks as will fit in memory, each running on all of the cores?  Or to dynamically assign the number of cores per task in a way that doesn't have the shortcomings mentioned above?